# Is there an R function for plotting the 3rd dimension of a correspondence analysis using FactoMineR (or any other package)?

Tags: r, correspondence-analysis

I am performing a correspondence analysis on categorical, frequency data pulled from archaeological site reports. I chose CA because, as I understand, it can handle presence/absence, which is often the nature of archaeological data. I used the FactoMineR and factoextra packages to create a nice biplot of the first and second dimensions. However, looking at the eigenvalue percentages, I'd really like to plot the 3rd dimension against the first two to visualize some associations/relationships that appear in the results (archaeologists often struggle with multivariate stats, myself included, and having a visual would help overall). However, I can't find any documentation on how to plot a third dimension, either using FactoMineR or factoextra, or any other package. Has anyone ever done this, or any workaround suggestions?

I've looked through the FactoMineR and factoextra documentation. I've also asked around, and have received suggestions to try ggbiplot and ggfortify; however those only seem to work with PCA, FA, etc. data.

```
lodgestotal4.ca <- CA(lodgestotal4) #run analysis
fviz_ca_biplot(lodgestotal4.ca, repel = TRUE) #biplot of dim 1 & 2
print(lodgestotal4.ca$col) #eigenvalues
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fviz_pca_ind(rnaseq_X.pca, axes = c(1, 3), #chose dimensions to plot
         col.ind = "cos2", # Color by the quality of representation
         gradient.cols = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
         repel = TRUE     # Avoid text overlapping
)
```

Like this?

Comment: Explain it please!

Comment: In the axes, you can simply specify, which dimensions you use. If c(1,2), the standard dimensions 1 and 2 will be used.  But if you change it to c(1,3), you’ll used dimensions 1 and 3 instead